# How to compare/sort date with array of dates in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Please Help me...

I'm storing current system date in variable `myDate` i.e `myDate = 11 Nov 2017`

Now I want to get last/previous `n` date from `myDate`.

**example :-** `n = 7`

`myDate - 7 => 05 Nov 17`

Now here I got **date1** `(currentDate) = 11 November 17` && **date2** `(previous n date) = 05 November 17`

I have fetched data from my core-data, which gives me this array of dates :

```
(
    "11 November 2017",
    "10 November 2017",
    "8 November 2017",
    "5 November 2017",
    "3 November 2017",
    "1 November 2017"
)
```

Now I want to store/fetch dates in-between `date1` and `date2`

So finally I should get this array :

```
(
        "11 November 2017",
        "10 November 2017",
        "8 November 2017",
        "5 November 2017"
 )
```

How can I do this, please help me.

Comment: Please help me...

Comment: Are the dates `NSString` or `NSDate` instances?

Comment: dates are in  NSString

Comment: Three options: 1) Use `NSDate` (recommended). 2) Map the strings to `NSDate` 3) Use a string comparable format like 2017-11-5

Comment: How can I do it, bcoz I'm getting array of Dates in NSString format while fetching from core-data. Can you please give me an example.

Comment: For option 1 you need to change the Core Data attribute type from `NSString` to `NSDate`. It's highly recommended to save dates always as `NSDate` in Core Data. For option 2 you need `NSDateFormatter` with date format `dd MMMM yyyy` and a repeat loop to convert all strings to `NSDate`. To compare the dates use `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`

Comment: I'll try out. Thanks a lot @vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aadi  try this..

```
NSMutableArray *arrOutput = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arrDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"11 November 2017",
                                @"10 November 2017",
                                @"8 November 2017",
                                @"5 November 2017",
                                @"3 November 2017",
                                @"1 November 2017", nil];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSString *strCurrentDate = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *currentDate = [df dateFromString:strCurrentDate];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = -7;
    NSDate *lastWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    for(int i=0; i<arrDates.count; i++)
    {
        NSDate *dateFormArray = [df dateFromString:[arrDates objectAtIndex:i]];
        if ([dateFormArray compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedAscending && [dateFormArray compare:lastWeek] != NSOrderedAscending)
        {
            [arrOutput addObject:[arrDates objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"current date = %@",strCurrentDate);
    NSLog(@"output = %@",arrOutput);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nirav, your answer doesn't work as I required. It prints every date as one day previous one. Suppose currentDate is 11 Nov 17, then it prints currentDate = 10 Nov 17. Also same case with dateFromArray. dateFrom Array should have only dates in-between currentDate && lastWeek. But it prints all dates as from myDate array.

Comment: @Aadi suppose current date is 11 nov 17 then output will be 5, 8 and 10 november as per your array.. right ?

Comment: You are just near to it, please try out.

Comment: i have change this --> NSLog(@"result = %@",[arrDates objectAtIndex:i]);

Comment: Yes  now its correct, giving desired result. But still it prints one day previous date. It gives me currentDate = 10 Nov 17 but it should be 11 Nov 17

Comment: yes, because `NSDate` will take UTC time. but it will not affect to your result.

Comment: Because of this whole array I'm getting one-day back date.

Comment: It is affecting to my result. Because I'want to show current date data also till lastWeek Date

Comment: In Final array I'm getting [10 Nov 17 ... 04 Nov 17] but it should be [11 Nov ... 05 Nov 17]

Comment: you can add [arrDates objectAtIndex:i] in your array so you can get your output

Comment: NSString *str = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; <-- initially you can print this string which will give you right current date. 11 November 2017

Comment: Yes its works perfectly. Thanks, just required small correction I've used this to pass NSDate *cDate = [NSDate date]; as currentDate  to compare